# Testing an app with sessions

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building an app with the upcoming Laravel 4 framework. I would like to write unit tests for it. The app uses sessions. Therefore, I have to recreate the user state to properly test everything.

Here's something I'd like to do:

```
User::login($user); // updates the session
$crawler = $this->client->request('GET', 'http://myapp.dev/');
$this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isOk());
$this->assertCount(1, $crawler->filter("#logout-button"));
```

However, `$this->client->request` creates a new request so the session doesn't get propagated.

The session is available in test. But when you use $this->client->request('GET', 'something'), the session for that request is not there anymore, because it uses an array driver. I could try to use the file driver, but how would I go about sending a custom session id to the request?

**How can I solve this? Can I pass the session id via a fake cookie? Or pass the session object some way or another?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$this->be($user)` instead of `Auth::login`. See early L4 docs here : https://github.com/laravel/docs/blob/master/testing.md

Comment: I'm not using the Auth package. And what if I want something else than what's included in the Auth package?

Comment: There is a second argument to `$this->be` to specify which Auth driver to use.

Comment: Again, I am not using the Auth package. At all. I want general session access in my testing env.

Comment: Hm, then try `$this->app['session']` see if the component is binded but I'm not sure.

Comment: $this->app['session'] is binded but it seems like the session is not started automatically. I'm not quite sure what is happening.